# How to prevent Flutter widgets resize When the keyboard appears?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, scrollview, textfield, scaffold

When the keyboard appears, the Flutter widgets resize. How to prevent this without using

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
```

if I make it false then I can't see the TextFormField because the keyboard been above it
so waht to do?
here is my code

```
    return Scaffold(
//      resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Image.asset('images/back_ui4.png',fit: BoxFit.fill,),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 0.7*MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,),
                  TextFormField()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child : Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Image.asset('images/back_ui4.png',fit: BoxFit.fill,),
            ),
            Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 0.7*MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,),
                  TextFormField()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I don't want to scroll the image

Comment: remove this from SizedBox (parent of Image) height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height and set height of ImageView)